# Copy values from a data entry like sheet and paste them into individual sheets, in a row based on a certain value in one cell

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, data-entry

I’m writing a macro to get values from a “DataEntry” sheet and pasting them into the sheet that has the same value in F1 on the individual sheets as is in the Column A on the main sheet

The DataEntry sheet is sheet number 2 that's visible in the workbook and the macro must look to paste values from visible sheet 3 onwards not in my first sheet called “Summary”

*update:* I managed to get it to work on only the visible sheets

I would also like it to paste it in a certain row based on the value in F2 on DataEntry (*see attached image number 1*) and the corresponding value in column B on the individual sheets (under the date heading *see attached image number 2*)

**Issues I have encountered thus far:**

1. I have not yet added the copy to a certain row portion to my code as I’m struggling to figure it out
2. I’ve initially copied all the F2 values to the main sheet and trying to paste all the values from B*:D* to their respective sheets
   by just running through the entire list

*update:* I’ve managed to get it to copy by using Cells.Address for my range and got it to run on the individual sheets

[Screenshot of “DataEntry” sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKIRM.png)

[Screenshot of the cells on typical individual sheet that the data must go to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yC8Zs.png)

This is the code that I have so far

```
Sub CopyDieseltoSheets()

Dim wsInput As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet
Set wsInput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataEntry")
Dim nextRow As Integer
nextRow = 3
Dim rng As Range
Dim shCount As Integer
shCount = 4
Dim TabCount As Long
TabCount = Sheets("COMPRESSOR AN01 - ROADSPAN").Index

Do

    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shCount).Visible <> xlSheetHidden Then
        
        With wsInput
              Set rng = .Range(Cells(nextRow, 2).Address(), Cells(nextRow, 4).Address())
              rng.Copy
                
              Set wsOutput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shCount)
             
                With wsOutput
                    .Range("C16:E16").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, _
                    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                End With

`I need to change the range in the output based on the value in F2 on the "DataEntry" sheet but not sure what is the best way to go about it
              
        End With
        
        nextRow = nextRow + 1
        
    Else
    
    End If
        
        shCount = shCount + 1

Loop Until shCount = TabCount + 1
  
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your `If` statement keeps referring to `wsInput.Name` which is going to be `DataEntry`; should that be `wsOutput.name`?

Comment: Instead of pasting, maybe you could try assigning the value of rng to the range in wsOutput? Would be a “cheaper” operations with fewer steps to it.

Comment: @ProfessorPantsless  `If wsOutput.Name <> wsInput.Name _
And wsOutput.Name <> "Summary" And wsOutput.Name <> "Start" _
And wsOutput.Visible = True Then` like this?

Comment: It's not clear from your question what the logic is to determine the range in the output. Can you provide some specific examples? Also, you should always qualify your `Sheets` reference because unqualified will use the active workbook, ie `ThisWorkbook.Sheets...`. Not sure if this is your issue, but the `Visible` property of a sheet can take on 3 values: `xlSheetVisible`, `xlSheetHidden`, and `xlSheetVeryHidden` (not `xlHidden`).

Comment: @professorpantless

I would like to put a certain date value in a cell (F2 in this case) on the “DataEntry” sheet and then it looks for that date value in column B on each individual sheet.
 Then, find the row number it finds that value in and puts the data in columns C to E of that row

Example, If I put ‘4’ in the F2 cell on “DataEntry”, I would like the macro to enter the data in columns C to E in the row that it finds the ‘4’ in column B 

Also, thank you for the best practice advice and the assistance with the sheet property, I will make those changes)

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that well enough @HavardKleven  . Would I have to make another range variable "rngOutput" and somehow set that to the value of the variable rng?

Comment: @VBA_Novice_123, see answer which should help to explain. Also, please upvote any comments you find helpful.

Comment: I cannot upvote as yet, as I only have 1 reputation point thus far @ProfessorPantsless .Will do so when I get to 15 reputation

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Find()` method of the `Range` object to achieve what you want. You can navigate to the cells you want from there using `Offset()` and `Resize`. As @HarvardKleven mentioned you can use `rng1 = rng2` to copy and paste values from `rng2` to `rng1`, which tends to be more efficient (ie, "cheaper") than using `copy` and `paste` methods in VBA.

The code below can replace your current `Do...Loop` and should do what you are looking for. Note there is an additional variable I have added `outputRng` as a `Range` object.

```
Do

    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shCount).Visible <> xlSheetHidden Then
        
        Set rng = wsInput.Range(Cells(nextRow, 2).Address(), Cells(nextRow, 4).Address())
                        
        Set wsOutput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shCount)
             
        ' find the value you are looking for in column B
        ' get the cell next to it (offset)
        ' resize this range to have the same number of columns as rng (resize)
        Set outputRng = wsOutput.Range("B:B").Find(rng.Value).Offset(0, 1).Resize(ColumnSize:=rng.Columns.Count)
        
        outputRng = rng 'will set the values from outputRng to the values from rng

        nextRow = nextRow + 1
    
    End If
        
        shCount = shCount + 1

Loop Until shCount = TabCount + 1
```